# Adding and using a Domain Admin during OSD, in MDT

Tags: sccm-2012, mdt-2012, mdt

So during my Windows 7 OSD.

Going by Company Politics
 I'm suppose to

A: Disabled the standardlized Administrator (Done, can do that in task sequence)
 B: Create a new Administrator called 'ITadmin' and set a fixed password
 C: Join a Domain (Done that aswell in the Task Sequence)
 D: Use a Domain Admin to install programs that would otherwise give problems if attempted to install through Local Admin, like Dynamics AX

As written I join the computer to the Domain During the OSD, and as Result have the correct
Domain Admins added as Administrators through GPO, but I don't know how to use them.

I'm looking at CustomSettings.ini in the MDT pack and thinking its gotta be possible to do it from here? or from the unattend.xml

in pseudo here is what I wanna Add:

**AddLocalAdmin:** ITadmin
**Password:** 1234
**UseThisAccountToInstallOSD:** Domain\Install_User
**Password:** 1234

Any help appreciated, can't seem to google my way out of this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can add domain users to the computer in the answer file using [UserAccounts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff716114.aspx), a child element under the [Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff715801.aspx) component. You state that you have GPOs that are adding the domain admins, so you probably don’t need the [DomainAccounts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff715449.aspx) information in your answer file, however you can use the [LocalAccounts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff715535.aspx) settings to add the local administrator account ‘ITAdmin’.

Also under the Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup component is the [AutoLogon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff716059.aspx) element. You can specify the domain account that you need as the autologon account that will be used to install software.

There are several xml examples of how these are used in the answer file on the pages linked that should help you get this setup properly.

Hope this helps,